# How to hide and show menu-items on action bar

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I have a menu item system implemented into my action bar, I am trying to get a menu item to become invisible once clicked and then to become visible again after clicking a different menu item.

The reason for this is to prevent a menu item getting clicked more than once.

I have done the following attempt below however, I get a null pointer exception error. I believe I may need to implement some if statements here but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tasklistmenu,menu);

    return true;
}//OnCreateOptionsMenu


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.allTasks:

            item.setVisible(false);


            MenuItem notStartedStatus = findViewById(R.id.notStartedStatus);
            notStartedStatus.setVisible(true);

            MenuItem inProgressStatus = findViewById(R.id.inProgressStatus);
            inProgressStatus.setVisible(true);

            MenuItem completeStatus = findViewById(R.id.completeStatus);
            completeStatus.setVisible(true);
```

**Log error**

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem 
android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

**NEW CODE**

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem allTasks = menu.findItem(R.id.allTasks);
    MenuItem notStartedStatus = menu.findItem(R.id.notStartedStatus);
    MenuItem completeStatus = menu.findItem(R.id.completeStatus);
    MenuItem inProgressStatus = menu.findItem(R.id.inProgressStatus);


    if(tasksIsVisible) {
        allTasks.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        allTasks.setVisible(false);
    }

    if(notStartedIsVisible) {
        notStartedStatus.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        notStartedStatus.setVisible(false);
    }

    if(completeIsVisible) {
        completeStatus.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        completeStatus.setVisible(false);
    }

    if(inProgressIsVisible) {
        inProgressStatus.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        inProgressStatus.setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;

}//OnPrepareOptions

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.allTasks:

            tasksIsVisible = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not enough to change the `isVisible` variable. You have to call the `setVisible()` method every time you want to change the visibility. That method does more than just setting a boolean value, so just changing a boolean value will not do.

After changing the `isVisible` value to false, you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` which will re-launch the menu by calling `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` again.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem notStartedStatus = menu.findItem(R.id.notStartedStatus);      
    if(isVisible) 
    {           
        notStartedStatus.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        notStartedStatus.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Try this code for making the menu items unvisible:

```
...
isVisible = false;
invalidateOptionsMenu();
...
```

Comment: I'm not too sure if I can completely understand your answer. I have updated my question with the new code, however it is not doing what I expected so you can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you should change the boolean value and then call invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: I'm not too sure where you mean for me to do this?

Comment: when you want to trigger action hide/unhide , ex : onOptionItemSelected

Comment: the problem I'm having with that is the isVisible (tasksIsVisible) variable is not recognised in the onOptionsItemSelected() method as it is a foreign variable to this method

Comment: You should create them outside of your onpreparemenu , they should be local

Comment: Sorry @ismail you're right. The problem is now my menu drawer has disappeared so I can't test.

Comment: hope my answer was helpful for the initial question

Comment: The drawer hadn't disappeared until I added in the OnPrepareOptionsMenu() method @ismail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193954/discussion-between-ismail-alaoui-and-alex-bingham).